# unable to use SetConnectionNameList method of MQQueueConnectionFactory

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Do any extra jar files or pre-configuration have to be done to use  `setConnectionNameList(String)` method present in `MQQueueConnectionFactory`?

```
import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;
MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setConnectionNameList("hostName(port),hostName(port)");
connectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
connectionFactory.setQueueManager("queueManagerName"); 
connectionFactory.setChannel("CLIENTCONNECTION");
```

Eclipse throws below stated error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>   The method setConnectionNameList(String) is undefined for the type MQQueueConnectionFactory

Answer (score 0):

`setConnectionNameList` was introduced in the WebSphere MQ 7.0.1 API. Is it possible you are using an older version of the MQ JARs?

Comment: Yes i'm using WebSphere MQ 7.0.1.                                                                        latest JAR what i find in google is com.ibm.mqjms-6.0.1.1.jar. Can you please let me know which version of JAR you are using?